# Do while statement is not acting as intended

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

We've been tasked to create a simple turn based game, but my do while loop is not working as intended, it doesn't stop at the required condition of while(p1.getHP() >= 0 && p2.getHP()>= 0);

for reference, here is a link to my code. 
http://pastebin.com/WyAfrWTE

it's not totally complete yet, I just want to take out this error before i finish it.

Comment: Can't you repro the issue with a small block of code, and then paste that code here?

Comment: i tried, but I dont know how to use this site's markdown, so I just pastebinned it.

Comment: @AcBayudan That's against the rules here.

Comment: @AcBayudan _"I dont know how to use this site's markdown"_ That's no excuse (there's [plenty of help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for this). Just indent code with four spaces and leave at least an empty line before and after the code block. Use the preview while editing, to check how it actually will look.

Comment: Please indent the code properly, and post a minimal example, in the question, that demonstrates the problem. Your code is so horrible that I can't tell whether that line is an empty `while` loop, or the end of a gargantuan `do...while` loop.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: The opening do is on line 146, the closing while is on line 305. Please fix your indentation!

Comment: Writing some functions may help the readability too.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote

```
while (p1.getHp() > 0 || p2.getHp() > 0)
```

Instead of

```
while (p1.getHp() > 0 && p2.getHp() > 0)
```

---

Also, `resetHp()` should **not** be

```
Life==100;
```

but rather

```
Life=100;
```

---

Third error:

```
while (again=1);
```

is an endless loop, you probably want:

```
while (again==1);
```

---

Judging by the errors I found by accident, I would advise you check your **complete** code for errors again, as I am sure that there are more hidden...

Comment: You got really good eyes.

Comment: @Nico still need glasses XD

Answer (score 2):

This code is horribly indented, not sure of the problem (and can't comment with low rep) but I will tell you your last line won't work:

```
while(again=1);
```

it should be

```
while(again==1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you `p1.getHP() >= 0 && p2.getHP()>= 0`. p1.getHP() always returns >=0 and p2.getHP always returns >= 0..

You have to make sure that p2.getHP() OR p1.getHP() returns a negative value at some point in time.

Comment: p2.getHP()/p1.getHP() always returns a negative value at some point, usually after 10 or so turns, but even when it goes below 0 the code doesnt recognize it and loops again and again.

Comment: You have to make sure. If the loop does not end, it means that the condition is still true. It's not a php defect but a bug in your source.